# passing parameters to dynamic templateurl

Tags: angularjs, url-routing

Assume of all pre-requisites done e.g. adding links at the load of html.
I have and angularjs posting call as

```
$location.path('/url1');
```

this goes to $routeProvider

```
$routeProvider.when('/url1', {
    templateUrl: '/public/url1.html/
})
```

above angularjs dynamic template loading works properly, now when i want to pass parameter then it does not work below

```
$location.path('/url1/:_id');

$routeProvider.when('/url1/:_id', {
    templateUrl: function(params) {
        return '/url1' + params._id + '.html';
    }
})
```

but i receive no parameterised url , so that i can access the parameters after posting.

Comment: But you want to change location to /url1/:_id and load /url1:_id.html file as a template?

Comment: yes location changes and includes parameters in url. In normal html url's the GET method form submission we can pass easily parameters but i referred to many posts that has no proper angularjs as i want for parametric url.

Comment: but your example works fine, could you write how you change your location?

Comment: the example works fine for direct url paths without passing params , but not with param, i need exact synatx for working with passing params

Comment: how do you pass params?